# xsd-schema-validator library not working on docker image Node and JAVA

Tags: java, node.js, docker

I'm using xsd-schema-validator which is A (XSD) schema validator for NodeJS that uses Java to perform the actual validation. You can see the library details on [github](https://github.com/nikku/node-xsd-schema-validator#why).

I'm testing the validator on my windows machine which seems to be working perfectly. the simple method as the follwoing :

```
const validator = require('xsd-schema-validator');
var openScenario = fs.readFileSync('./Schemas/test.xosc','UTF8');

validator.validateXML(openScenario, './Schemas/OpenScenario-1-1/OpenSCENARIO.xsd', function (err :any, result : any) 
{

  if(err)
  {
    console.log(err)
    console.log(result)
    var jsonObject = JsonObject()
    // jsonObject["openScenario"].version = version;
    jsonObject["openScenario"].isOpenScenarioValid = result.valid;
    jsonObject["openScenario"].errorDetails = result.messages
  }
    var jsonResult = JSON.stringify(jsonObject,null, "\t")
    // fn(jsonResult)
  
});
```

The above code returns the desired result and both of the xml and xsd are working. However, once i wanted to docker my application using the following dockerfile, and without changing anything in the method, the validator stopped working:
`

```
FROM node:18-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk-headless && \
    apt-get clean ;
  

RUN java -version
RUN javac -version

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
RUN export JAVA_HOME 

WORKDIR /code
EXPOSE 8443
COPY code/package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY code/. .

CMD ["node","app.js"]
```

`

When I run my application i get the following message :

```
Error: invalid xml (status=WITH_ERRORS)
    at buildError (/code/node_modules/xsd-schema-validator/lib/validator.js:205:14)
    at finish (/code/node_modules/xsd-schema-validator/lib/validator.js:171:34)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/code/node_modules/xsd-schema-validator/lib/validator.js:214:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
{ valid: false, result: 'WITH_ERRORS', messages: [] }
```

--

my docker operating environment for node and java as the following :

root@78d0c886dc22:/code# `java -version`
openjdk version "11.0.18" 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.18+10-post-Debian-1deb11u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.18+10-post-Debian-1deb11u1, mixed mode, sharing)
root@78d0c886dc22:/code# `node -v`
v18.14.0
root@78d0c886dc22:/code# `javac -version`
javac 11.0.18
root@78d0c886dc22:/code# `(dirname $(dirname $(readlink -f $(which javac))))`
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64

Would you please assist with that, I tried to use different java images as well but not working.?